when i run my spring boot web application in IntelliJ i'm getting Error executing DDL "create table
`Error executing DDL "create table "C:\Users\Public"."question" ("id" integer not null, "category" varchar(255), "difficultylevel" varchar(255), "option1" varchar(255), "option2" varchar(255), "option3" varchar(255), "option4" varchar(255), "questiontitle" varchar(255), "rightanswer" varchar(255), primary key ("id"))" via JDBC [ERROR: schema "C:\Users\Public" does not exist
Position: 14]
`My application.properties be like
note : Import statements removed

    spring.application.name=quizapp
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=0000
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${PUBLIC}


QuestionController :



@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "question")

public class QuestionController {

  @Autowired
  QuestionService questionService;


    @GetMapping("allQuestions")
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions()

    {
        return questionService.getAllQuestions();

    }


}


Question.java :

;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

    private Integer id;
    private String category;
    private String questiontitle;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private String option4;
    private String rightanswer;
    private String difficultylevel;




}

QuestionService.java :




@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    QuestionDao questionDao;

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Question> all = questionDao.findAll();
return all;
    }

}


QuestionDao.java



@Repository
public interface QuestionDao extends JpaRepository<Question,Integer> {



}

QuizApplications.java :

package com.thrinadh.quizapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QuizappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizappApplication.class, args);
    }

}

`

and my Error :

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table "C:\Users\Public"."question" ("id" integer not null, "category" varchar(255), "difficultylevel" varchar(255), "option1" varchar(255), "option2" varchar(255), "option3" varchar(255), "option4" varchar(255), "questiontitle" varchar(255), "rightanswer" varchar(255), primary key ("id"))" via JDBC [ERROR: schema "C:\Users\Public" does not exist
Position: 14]
at

i'm expecting the data in the table of My PostgreSQL to be in the outputPostgreSQL Table `

"C:\Users\Public" is not a valid schema.
try juste create table "question" .....

how i do that and where

What's contained in the ${PUBLIC} env variable which you assign to spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema in your properties? Try to just delete this property or change this value to public instead of ${PUBLIC}.
